# Introductory/Intuitive Functional Analysis Book

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can you recommend a gentle introduction to the abstract thinking and motivation of functional analysis? I'm looking for a book that holds you by the hand and shows the details of exercises, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of the well written books on Functional analysis that I've seen, [Kreyszig](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504599) is the most elementary. The Amazon reviews seem to agree with me.

Answer (score 3):

Erwin Kreyszig *Introductory Functional Analysis*
or Rynne & Youngson *Linear Functional Analysis*.

Both are elementary, well-written and self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *Introduction to Functional Analysis* by S.C. Bose. The text is really good and simple to understand; there is a considerable number of solved exercises and examples. I'm getting a desire to re-read!